# Is it possible to disarm or safely set off traps that I can see on the ground?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In some areas there are traps that I can clearly see on the ground.

[image: a bear trap]
*Yep, I see you...*

I want to disarm or set them off safely but I can't (that way I don't accidentally walk into them the next time I'm in the area).

All of these I've tried does nothing and provides no options and usually just hurts me:

- Sneaking up to it
- Walking up to it
- Running onto it
- Moving around with a shield
- Attacking it
- Using spells/abilities on it

I figure I could probably lure enemies onto it but I usually kill them off before I ever encounter these.

Is there anything I can do to disarm or set these off safely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disarm traps once you get your Detect Hidden skill to rank 4.

[image]

Note that if you get it all the way up to rank 8, not only can you disarm the traps, but you can salvage components from them.

Answer (score 5):

The ability to disable traps becomes available at level 4 in Detect Hidden.

Until then, you need to either trigger and escape (most magic rune traps) or simply avoid (bear traps).

Comment: Ah figures, I've been spending my points mostly in Stealth, Blacksmithing and Alchemy.  I haven't even really looked at the other descriptions yet.